# overflow:auto is not working on a BlackBerry device

Tags: javascript, html, css, blackberry

I am developing a simple application using HTML and JavaScript / CSS. I have a `div` container in HTML code and I have defined its style in my CSS file as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container
{
height:150px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I am filling the `div` *container*  on runtime. When the content goes outside the container, an automatic scroll bar appears on browser, but same is not happening on BlackBerry.

My BlackBerry software version is 6.0 and above.

Comment: If this is not a typo `#`->`.`, I highly doubt that this code is only on Blackberry malfunctioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IDs you need to use the `#` and for classes the `.` Notation. "container" is an ID in your html but in CSS you are using it as class. Remove the dot and write `#` instead.